# How to adjust width of <td>

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with a multiple "sections". First there is the title, then the table data.

```
<table>
    <tr> <th>First Name </th> </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>Smith</td>
       <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>Jackson</td>
       <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>Johnson</td>
       <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>4</td>
       <td>Nilson</td>
       <td>35</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The width of the `<td>` is always as wide as the title's.  How can I adjust the width of the `<td>`?

I've tried giving the `<td>` a class and adjusting it that way but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how tables work.
You either give a th for every column:

```
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>Smith</td>
   <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>Jackson</td>
   <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>Johnson</td>
   <td>67</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>Nilson</td>
   <td>35</td>
</tr>
```

or you use colspan:

```
<tr>
    <th colspan="3">First Name </th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>Smith</td>
   <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>Jackson</td>
   <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>Johnson</td>
   <td>67</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>Nilson</td>
   <td>35</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for something more like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 30px"></th>
      <th style="width: 60px">First Name</th>
      <th style="width: 30px"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Nilson</td>
      <td>35</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```